# OpenCTI - retrieve data from call object

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, opencti, call-center

We're using OpenCTI for our call center connector, and we're trying to call out to a web service from a button click on a custom object layout, passing arguments including the call UUID passed in the call object. I'm just struggling to get this data in a form I can pass it via a controller.

I've come across this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getcallattacheddata.htm which seems to fit the bill. I've tested the code example here in a sandbox with an active call, but in most tests getCallObjectIds is returning null, and in the rare instances I'm getting a call object Id, using it in setCallAttachedData is popping "Call attached data is undefined Call Type is undefined"

My test vf page:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/43.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Note: Open CTI needs to set call type to before getting it, and call type is INTERNAL/INBOUND/OUTBOUND.   
*/

       function testSetCallAttachedData() {
          //callData must be a JSON string. We assume that your browser has
          //access to a JSON library.
          //var callData = JSON.stringify({"ANI":"4155551212", "DNIS":"8005551212"});

          //Set the call attached data associated to call id 'call.1'
          sforce.console.cti.setCallAttachedData('call.1', callData, 'outbound');
       }


    var callback2 = function (result) {
        console.log('PayIPSI/callback2: result ' + result);
        console.log('PayIPSI/callback2: result.success ' + result.success);
        console.log('PayIPSI/callback2: result.data ' + result.data);
        console.log('PayIPSI/callback2: result.type ' + result.type);
        alert('Call attached data  is ' + result.data + '\n Call Type is ' + result.type);

    };

    /* Retrieving call ID of first call that came in and 
     * calling getCallAttachedData() to retrieve call data.
     */

    var callback1 = function (result) {
        console.log('PayIPSI/callback1: result.ids ' + result.ids);
        if (result.ids && result.ids.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0 ; i < result.ids.length ; i++) {
                console.log('PayIPSI/callback1: result.id '+i+': ' + result.id[i]);
            }
            /** test set data
            var callData = JSON.stringify({"ANI":"4155551212", "DNIS":"8005551212"});
            //Set the call attached data associated to call id 'call.1'
            sforce.console.cti.setCallAttachedData(result.ids[0], callData, 'inbound');
            **/
            sforce.console.cti.getCallAttachedData(result.ids[0], callback2, {getCallType:true});
        }
    };

    //Note that we are using the CTI submodule here
    function testGetCallAttachedData() {
        sforce.console.cti.getCallObjectIds(callback1);
    };

</script>
<h1>CTI</h1>
<button onclick="testGetCallAttachedData()">getAttachedData</button>
```

Any idea what I'm missing here, or is there another way I can retrieve data from an active call object on request from Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this, the call centre connector package wasn't attaching the data correctly (setCallAttachedData) which is why it wasn't coming through. I thought it might have been a mistake on my part in the code above, but I guess the lesson learned here is your chosen CTI may not be attaching any data as expected with OpenCTI if their dev team haven't specifically been told that's a requirement!

Comment: yep -- Salesforce doesn't seem to enforce much on creation of CallObject.  It doesn't even enforce triggering the OpenCTI events...